# QTreeView not displaying file icons (PySide6)

Tags: python, qtreeview, pyside6

I recently built an app in PyQt5, and I was using a QTreeView to display all the items inside a folder. Today a switched to PySide6 and for some reason the TreeView is not showing the icons of the files/folders.
I am going to toss in some images as examples.

[image: This was using PyQt5 (also works with PySide2)]

[image: This is using PySide6]

Did something change between the two releases? I tried looking for something online but nothing pops up.
This is the code I am using (I don't know if it helps)

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
import sys
import logic


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Init UI
        self.width = 540
        self.height = 380
        self.setGeometry(
            qtw.QStyle.alignedRect(
                qtc.Qt.LeftToRight,
                qtc.Qt.AlignCenter,
                self.size(),
                qtg.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry(),
            ),
        )
        self.tree = qtw.QTreeView()
        self.model = qtw.QFileSystemModel()

        # Items
        self.path_input = qtw.QLineEdit()
        path_label = qtw.QLabel("Enter a path to begin: ")
        check_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Check")  # To display the items
        clear_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Clear")  # To clear the TreeView
        self.start_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Start")  # To start the process
        self.start_btn.setEnabled(False)

        # Layouts
        top_h_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        top_h_layout.addWidget(path_label)
        top_h_layout.addWidget(self.path_input)
        top_h_layout.addWidget(check_btn)
        bot_h_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        bot_h_layout.addWidget(clear_btn)
        bot_h_layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)
        main_v_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        main_v_layout.addLayout(top_h_layout)
        main_v_layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        main_v_layout.addLayout(bot_h_layout)
        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

        check_btn.clicked.connect(self.init_model)
        clear_btn.clicked.connect(self.clear_model)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.show()

    def init_model(self):
        if logic.check(self.path_input.text()):
            self.model.setRootPath(self.path_input.text())
            self.tree.setModel(self.model)
            self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path_input.text()))
            self.tree.setColumnWidth(0, 205)
            self.tree.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
            self.path_input.clear()
            self.start_btn.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            qtw.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Path not found.")
            self.path_input.clear()

    def clear_model(self):
        self.tree.setModel(None)
        self.path_input.clear()

    def start(self):
        logic.start(self.path_input.text())
        qtw.QMessageBox.information(self, "Done", "Process completed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the logic.py file:

```
import os
import shutil


def check(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def start(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            movie_name = filename
            strip_name = filename[:-4]
            print(f"Creating directory for {movie_name}")
            os.mkdir(strip_name)
            print("Moving item to new directory.")
            shutil.move(f"{path}\\{movie_name}", f"{path}\\{strip_name}\\{movie_name}")
            print("\n")
    print("Done.")


# For testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    usr_input = input("Path: ")
```

Comment: <PySide6.QtGui.QAbstractFileIconProvider object at 0x000001E10523E480> This is the output

Comment: Still nothing is showing. The names of the files are spaced more from the side. It's like it's loading "invisible" icons

Comment: No there is just  a os.path.isdir()

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm going to include it in the post. Gimme a sec

Comment: This is working perfectly! How does this work?
Oh and can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: To publish my answer I need a piece of information: With my updated code then what do you get as a log? So I can understand the cause since in Linux I do not see that problem

Comment: You can try the updated gist code and put the log you get as a comment in the gist, don't use SO as the format is horrible

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SMMO0/1848c6f6d2b7d672a3ae9d5455b99f0a This should be better

Comment: I have updated my original gist, try it again please

Comment: It's working but I noticed that it only shows the icons for the folders. Every other file is still blank.

Comment: I don't know if it's supposed to be this way, but the folder icons are working correctly, every other file is just the "white paper sheet" icon.

Comment: Have you tried the updated code of my answer?

Comment: yes I just tried it

Comment: Just for testing, what do you get if you change SP_FileIcon with SP_MediaPlay?

Comment: I get a black triangle. Guess i'ts the icon for playing medias. The thing is that with pyside 2 I get the class windows 10 icons. I also get pdf or python files icons.

Comment: Is that that is the real problem that I point out in my answer: There is a bug in PySide6 (perhaps in Qt6) in windows since in Linux it works correctly. So a workaround is the one that I indicate, if you want the Windows icons then get the .png and change `qtw.QApplication.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_FileIcon)` for `qtg.QIcon("/path/of/your_icon.png")`

Comment: Ok so that's a bug with pyside6. Nice to know that it wasn't my problem then. Thanks for the help! I'm going to mark the answer as correct since it's actually working

Comment: You should read the responses and not just copy-paste the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug: the icons are invalid (maybe a plugin is missing, or is not correctly installed or does not have all its dependencies).

A workaround is to implement a custom QFileIconProvider:

```py
class FileIconProvider(qtw.QFileIconProvider):
    def icon(self, _input):
        if isinstance(_input, qtc.QFileInfo):
            if _input.isDir():
                return qtw.QApplication.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_DirIcon)
            elif _input.isFile():
                return qtw.QApplication.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_FileIcon)
        else:
            if _input == qtg.QAbstractFileIconProvider.Folder:
                return qtw.QApplication.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_DirIcon)
            elif _input == qtg.QAbstractFileIconProvider.File:
                return qtw.QApplication.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_FileIcon)
        return super().icon(_input)
```

```
self.model.setIconProvider(FileIconProvider())
```